# c++: Reading a file line by line

Tags: c++, file-io, filepath

I'm wondering if there's a C++ way of opening a file and reading the input line by line.

I encountered the following code that accomplishes the task:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  ifstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("example.txt");
  return 0;
}
```

I'm encouraged to not use any C functions or commands.

The thing is, my "example.txt" is in the form of a string, and using str.c_str() is a C function, so I guess I have two ways to solve the issue.

Is there another way to read input from a file line by line? Perhaps using something that will accept a string as a parameter for the filepath? Is there a C++ way of doing things? :)

Or, is there another way to convert the string in to a const char *, which is what the myfile.open() function needs?

Many thanks in advance!

EDIT: My lack of practivity and research led me to think c_str() was a C function, and it isn't. My apologies. Since it isn't I have found my answer.

Comment: `c_str()` is not a C function, it's a legitimate member function of a standard C++ library class (`std::string`). I don't understand your objection to it. This issue seems entirely orthogonal to your reading a file line-by-line question or have I misunderstood?

Comment: You say "the following code that accomplishes the task:" but the example you posted doesn't. Copy and paste error?

Comment: Also, you say "I have two ways to solve the issue" but you don't say what the issue is, or which two ways you have to solve it.

Comment: If I read your question correctly, you want to avoid string literals like `"example.txt"` altogether, is that right? That might turn out to be problematic.

Comment: @Mr Lister, That's right, but if str.c_str() is not a C function, then I will use it. My apologies to everyone, it was my mistake. The code I pasted was to illustrate one line, but I figured pasting the context would make things clearer. I will edit the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++11's `fstream` constructor accepts `string`. In most cases, you want to use `fstream`'s constructor, rather than `.open()` - you save one line and one function call.

For reading the file line-by-line, you should use [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Also note that `string::c_str()` is still C++ function, not C one, as well as `fstream`'s constructor taking `const char *`. Most of (if not all, I'm not 100% sure) C standard library function are also included in C++ standard.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I was wondering if there was a c++ way to do things, and this seems to be it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since the issue about str.c_str() is already answered, I'm just gonna add a bit about getting inputs line by line. for example, you wanna take 2 ints input per line, extract them, and put it into a vector.

```
fstream fs(filename.c_str(), ios_base::in);
string line;
stringstream ss;
int a,b;
vector<int> d; 
int numlines;
int i;
for (i = 0; getline(fs, line); i++) {
  for (ss.str(line); ss >> a >> b; d.push_back(a), d.push_back(b)) {}
  ss.clear();
}
numlines = i;
```

Hope you get the idea of using `getline()` and `fstream()`

Answer (score -3):

It's going to look very similar.  You'll want an `ifstream` instead of an `ofstream`, you'll want the `>>` operator, and assuming your file has more than one line, you'll need a loop and the `ifstream::feof()` function.

Comment: It's better to use `std::getline()` as reading function and loop condition.

Comment: `ifstream` doesn't have a `feof()` function although it's base class `basic_ios<char>` has `eof()` but it is almost always a bad idea to use it in a loop; it is usually preferable to use the success or otherwise of some flavour of read operation as a loop condition. (You might want to use `eof()` after the loop has terminated to determine whether the loop terminated due to end of stream or some error, but that is different.)